# emplace_back on std::vector

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I don't understand why the following code does not compile due to a "bad" usage of emplace_back. Could you please tell me what is wrong with it and what workaround I could use?

```
#include <vector>

class Test {
 private:
  std::size_t n_;
  std::vector<double> a_;
  std::vector<double> b_;

 public:
  Test(std::size_t n, std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list)
      : n_(n), a_(list.begin()[0]), b_(list.begin()[1]){};
};

int main() {
  Test t{5, {3, 4}};

  std::vector<Test> v;
  v.emplace_back(5, {3, 4});

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: use v.emplace_back(Test(5, {3, 4})); to add a Test object to the vector

Comment: [OT]: if the initializer list is supposed to be always of the size 2, consider using `std::array<std::size_t, 2>`, or replace by two parameters

Comment: @piotr: this code is obviously a real code. I made it simpler than it was, and I agree it looks stupid that way.

Comment: @user3668810 - creating a `Test` object pretty much defeats the purpose of `emplace_back`; you could just as well call `push_back`. The point of `emplace_back` is that it **doesn't** require an object, but will construct one in place from its arguments, eliminating a copy operation.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for pointing that out. I've read a bit about the two methods (push_back and emplace_back) and now I don't really see what's the point of having both of them in stl.

Comment: @PeteBecker I suppose it's the only way to make sure that the copy constructor doesn't get called (otherwise, the copy operation may or may not get optimized out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

{3, 4} have no type here, so, you need to explicitly state that you are using initializer-list, like this:

```
v.emplace_back(5, std::initializer_list<std::size_t>{3, 4});
```

Comment: `{3,4}` *does* have a type.  It's just that it is `std::initializer_list<int>`, not the required `std::initializer_list<size_t>`.

Comment: I am puzzled why it has no type here and why it does have one when I directly construct Test t.

Comment: @MartinBonner I've tried to change Test constructor to accept initializer_list<int> - still not working

Comment: @MartinBonner: no, it *does not* have a type, hence it cannot be deduced, hence OP has an error

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki:  Interesting.  "cpp.sh" was happy with `auto test = {3,4};`  My instinct was that an expression in C++ typically always has a type, and it is based *just on the expression*, not on the context.  However a little more experimentation reveals that `{3,4}` does *not* behave like an expression of type `iterator_list`.  Instead it is a particular construct which is only allowed in certain places.

Comment: @MartinBonner there's a special rule for `auto`, that does not apply to templates in general